# XMPP - Using lib Smack remove user from group(conference) in MUC

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat, groupchat

We are integrating *MUC* in our app for group chat. where we can create group(conference) and adding members. Questions are-

1. Removed member still getting group messages. What is proper way of remove a member from group?
2. How to get total members of group (online/offline)?

We are using following methods to remove a members-

```
 public void kickOutRoomMember(String groupJid, String memberNickName) {
    MultiUserChat muc;
    try {
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        }
        muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(groupJid);
        muc.kickParticipant(memberNickName, "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void removeOutRoomMember(String groupJid, String memberNickName) {
    MultiUserChat muc;
    try {
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        }
        muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(groupJid);
        muc.banUser(memberNickName, "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theorically you are right.
Just check

1. If user who invokes banUser has grants to do it
2. to pass bare
   jid and not memberNickName as first parameter in method.

[javadoc](https://docs.jivesoftware.com/smack/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#banUser(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
muc.banUser("Mickey Mouse", ""); //does not works
muc.banUser("mickeymouse@server","") // will works
```

Answer (score 0):

Install "Rest API" plugin.

Rest API plugin provides all the API related group. Create Or delete a group, Add or remove a member from a group, get all members of group etc..